# Limits at infinity of a function and its derivative

Tags: limits, derivatives, gre-exam

> [image]

I do not know how to solve this question, could anyone help me please?

Comment: Why not start by coming up with some examples to rule out some of the possibilities? Do you know any functions with $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$? also with $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0$?

Comment: ok I will do @GerryMyerson   a useful piece of advice for me thanks.

Comment: Could you please title your questions with something that indicates _what the question is about_ rather than just a reference to where in some obscure filing system you found the problem? Thank you.

Comment: Could u suggest a Title for me as I thought in this issue but I could not find @HenningMakholm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is A. Since $\lim_{x\to \infty}f'(x)$ exists, suppose by contradiction that $\lim_{x\to \infty}=L\ne 0.$ For some $r$ we have $$x>r\implies |f'(x)-L|<|L|/2\implies |f'(x)|>|L|/2\implies$$ $$\implies \exists y\in (x,x+1)\text { such that }|f(x+1)-f(x)|=\left|\frac {f(x+1)-f(x)}{(x+1)-x}\right|=$$ $$=|f'(y)|>|L|/2.$$ But if $L\ne 0$ then $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)$ cannot exist when  $x>r\implies |f(x+1)-f(x)|>|L|/2.$

OR You can eliminate C,D, and E with $f(x)=\tan^{-1}x,$ and eliminate B on the grounds that  there may be arbitrarily large $x$ where $f''(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: I think the first line lacks $f'(x)$ after the limit sign.

Comment: why did you take the epsilon by$ |L|/2$ ?

Comment: It is not clear for me why u get in the third line that $|f`(x)| > |L|/2 $..... could u clarify it for me please?

Comment: And why the fourth line (the third implication) you are sure that it exists.... could u clarify this for me please?

Comment: (1). Taking $|L|/2$ as an $\epsilon$  was convenient, as it was sufficient for the Q.....(2). If |$f'(x)-L|<|L|/2$ and  $L\ne 0$ then $f'(x)\in  (-3|L|/2,-|L|/2)\cup(| L|/2,3|L|/2)$, so $|f'(x)>|L|/2. $ We could also say simply that if $L\ne 0$ then $\{x: |f'(x)|\leq |L|/2 \}$ has an upper bound , else $f'(x)$ can't  converge to $L$ as $x\to \infty.$.... (3). The existence of $y\in (x,x+1) $ such that ... (et cetera) is the Mean Value Theorem,  verbatim.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use the mean value theorem on the interval $[n,n+1]$.

Comment: For which function and how?

Comment: You obtain $f(n+1) - f(n) = f'(\xi_{n})$ for some $\xi_n \in [n, n+1]$ and all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Taking the limit $n \to \infty$ on both sides shows that A is the right answer.

Comment: why $ lim ( f(n + 1) - f(n)) = 0 $ as n tends to $\infty$?

Comment: @Intuition because $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)$ exists.

Comment: exists does not mean it is equal zero .

Comment: For any real sequence of numbers $a_n$, if $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n $ exists, that implies that $\lim_{n\to\infty} ( a_{n+1} - a_{n} ) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Consider the map $f_1:(0,\infty)\to\Bbb R$ defined by $f_1(x)=1/x$. Options (d) and (e) can thus be eliminated.

Whereas the map $f_2:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ defined by $f(x)=1$ serves as a counter example for (c)

Comment: So clear examples thank u :).